# Finding, grouping and deleting the duplicate records in MS SQL and keeping the oldest

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that holds the employee's bank account records. There are duplicate records of the last record created by a user, which were created due to daily job execution.

For example: for Employee E1 below are the bank account records in DB

```
Jan 1 2015 - Bank X
Jan 1 2018 - Bank Y
Jan 1 2020 - Bank X
```

Here multiple duplicate records for Bank X and Y after each manual change on 1st Jan of 2015,18 and 20.

Now, I have to delete the duplicate records which are duplicate in terms of values of columns "BankName" and "BankAccountNumber".

Here in this scenario, the records should remain in system are all those which are updated on Jan 1 of years 2015, 2018 and 2020 even though the name and account number is the same for Bank X.

The columns we are considering in the table for preparing script are:

```
1. Recordid(Uniqueidentifier) primary key
2. Recordsequence(INT) Identity column by 1
3. EmployeeID(INT) <set of records are linked to an employee through  of employee table>.
```

My current Logic is to find the duplicate and delete the records:

```
;WITH BARecords
AS (
    SELECT recordid
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY employeeID
            ,BankName
            ,AccountNumber ORDER BY recordsequence
            ) row_num
    FROM employeebankaccount WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE employeeid IN (
            SELECT Id
            FROM @EMPLOYEEIDs
            )
    )
DELETE
FROM BARecords
WHERE row_num > 1
```

My current logic will remove the Bank X details from Jan 1 2020 as well and will keep only Jan 1 2015.
As the user have updated Bank X again that should also remain in the system of creation date Jan1 2020.

Comment: You should stop splattering NOLOCK all over the place. Especially in a system that is dealing with bank accounts and other financial concerns. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: `NOLOCK` *creates* duplicates - the same row can appear multiple times. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean `don't take locks`, on the contrary, it takes *extensive* locks. It means don't *respect* locks, even if the data isn't commited yet or worse, being moved from one data page to the next. That's how you can get the same row twice or not at all.

Comment: One scenario is to add a flag `current account record`, set that instead of deleting records and when you need to update  set the flag to inactive and add the new record. Your audit trail remains in the current table.

Comment: Perhaps inverse the order by into `desc` ?

Comment: I am using No Lock as it will be on PROD and also it will be executing in Non Business Hours. Really- thanks for your comments.

Comment: @GospodinTanev- where exactly you are suggesting to reverse the order?